# Terraform dynamic block syntax

Tags: terraform

I have the following terraform code of `aws_lb_target_group` resource

```
dynamic "health_check" {
    for_each = contains(keys(each.value), "health_check_settings") ? each.value.health_check_settings == true ? ["health_check"] : [] : []
    iterator = hc
    content {
 port = contains(keys(each.value), "health_check_port") ? each.value.health_check_port : "traffic-port"
      protocol = contains(keys(each.value), "health_check_protocol") ? each.value.health_check_protocol : "HTTP"
....
    }
}
```

And I don't understand the part of  `for_each = ["health_check"]`

It's just a tuple of one string, not an object. In case of `health_check_settings=true` how would the data will be passed to the for each.

Answer (score 0):

It's done in order to make this block conditional.
The actual value of `for_each` doesn't matter because we use each from higher `for_each` context.